# Is there a way to delimit a file scanner with spaces, but keep a first and last name separated with a space as one string?

Tags: java, string, substring

I'm trying to get a Scanner to read the lines of a file, and delimit the values with spaces, but also keep the first and last name together as one string.

Here's an example:

Given this as a plain text file:

```
Rachael Adams 3.36 1.93
Foluke Akinradewo 4.81 1.14
Kayla Banwarth 2.98 0.5
Michelle Bartsch 0.28 1.42
Krista Vansant 2.78 0.86
Courtney Thompson 0.59 0.93
Kelly Murphy 1.15 0.58
Lauren Gibbemeyer 2.25 0.5
Alexis Crimes 3.89 1.34
Tori Dixon 0.92 1.62
Nicole Fawcett 4.01 0.61
Alisha Glass 1.96 1.55
Natalie Hagglund 2.49 0.52
Kim Hill 1.53 1.76
Cursty Jackson 0.69 1.44
```

I need to be able to sort each field separately, like this:

```
String s = "Kim Hill";
double d1 = 1.53;
double d2 = 1.76;
```

So that I can pass these into my constructor for each Person object.
Here is what I have tried:

```
    Roster(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File rosterFile = new File(fileName);
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(rosterFile);

    while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String lineString = fileScanner.nextLine();
        String name = lineString.substring(0, lineString.length() - 10);
        Double attack = Double.valueOf(lineString.substring(lineString.length() - 9, lineString.length() - 5));
        Double defense = Double.valueOf(lineString.substring(lineString.length() - 5));
        peopleArrayList.add(new Person(name, attack, defense));
    }
    sizeOfRoster = peopleArrayList.size();
    fileScanner.close();
}
```

The trouble I am having is that some of the lines contain 0.5 in the evaluation data instead of 0.50, so my `lineString.length` is not applicable here. My training data had the extra digit so now I have to figure out how to do this a different way.

Comment: A regex expression would solve this easily.

Comment: Are all names guaranteed to have be of the form <firstname lastname>? No middle or multiple names ever?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
        String name = null;
        double attack = 0, defense = 0;
        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
            while(s.hasNext()) {
                name = s.next() + " "+ s.next();
                attack = s.nextDouble();
                defense = s.nextDouble(); 

                peopleArrayList.add(new Person(name, attack, defense));

                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(name);
                System.out.println(attack);
                System.out.println(defense);
            }
            s.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

output:

```
Rachael Adams
3.36
1.93

Foluke Akinradewo
4.81
1.14

Kayla Banwarth
2.98
0.5

Michelle Bartsch
0.28
1.42

Krista Vansant
2.78
0.86

Courtney Thompson
0.59
0.93

Kelly Murphy
1.15
0.58

Lauren Gibbemeyer
2.25
0.5

Alexis Crimes
3.89
1.34

Tori Dixon
0.92
1.62

Nicole Fawcett
4.01
0.61

Alisha Glass
1.96
1.55

Natalie Hagglund
2.49
0.52

Kim Hill
1.53
1.76

Cursty Jackson
0.69
1.44
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the loop with this:

```
while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String lineString = fileScanner.nextLine();
    String[] inputs = lineString.split(" ");
    String name = inputs[0] + " " + inputs[1];
    Double attack = Double.valueOf(inputs[2]);
    Double defense = Double.valueOf(inputs[3]);
    peopleArrayList.add(new Person(name, attack, defense));
}
```